# Python 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

Im trying to test out some stuff so I can make a python text adventure, but its not working. Here is the code:

```
calories = [3]

fooland= ("fooland")
area=fooland
joint= ("joint")

while area=="fooland":
talk=raw_input("Where to go?")

if talk==joint:
    area=joint

else:
    print "You cant do that!"


while area=="joint":
order=raw_input("What to order?")

if order=="fries":
    print "You eat like a BAWS"
    calories.append[2]

else:
    print "You cant eat that, but here is some grease!"
    calories.append[6]

 if [calories < 10]:
print "YOU ARE FAT"
```

But i get this error:

```
'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What am i doing wrong and how can i fix it?

Comment: Delete the square brackets around "calories < 10" in the last "if" statement.

Comment: @jrennie Tried it and it makes me delete the colon in `calories < 10:` and still gives me the same error

Comment: If you haven't yet, please work through the python tutorial http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call a method (like `append`), you wrap the parameters in () not [].

Comment: Tried that but i got: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 26, in <module>
    calories.append(6)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'`

Answer (score 1):

I also met this problem ever, and I found that the reason is that I wrote `[]`after function invoke wrongly:

```
 f.pop[para1]   // wrong 
 f.pop(para1)   // correct
```

Just change `[]` into `()` and program can work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
    if (int(calories) < 10):
      print "YOU ARE FAT"
```